# My loop keeps running a particular method which i want to run once

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to save data into firebase database but i put the method that actually saves the data in a if..else statement and the if...else statement in a for loop because i need to check for different conditions before running the method, there are series of if statements in the for loop, but I am starting to get really confused bacause the method keeps running and i don't see why, please help

```
for(DataSnapshot datasnapshot : snapshot.getChildren()){
    if(datasnapshot.child("email").getValue().toString().equals(Prevalent.currentOnlineUser.getEmail())){continue;}
    if(datasnapshot.child("username").getValue().toString().equals(Prevalent.currentOnlineUser.getUsername())){continue;}
    if(datasnapshot.child("username").getValue().toString().equals(textUsername)){
        Toast.makeText(Profile_Page_Activity.this, "Username already exists, try again", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }else{
        if(datasnapshot.child("email").getValue().toString().equals(textemail)){
            Toast.makeText(Profile_Page_Activity.this, "E-mail id taken please provide another one ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }else{
            uploadprofileimage();
        }
    }
}
```

The `uploadprofileimage()` is the method i am trying to run ONCE given certain conditions.

Comment: Did you try debugging and see what happens?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add  a `break` after executing your function. Something like this:

```
else{
  uploadprofileimage();
  break;
}
```

Else, the loop would just keep running since there is nothing stopping it.

Comment: Thanks a lot, this worked of course, I cannot believe i didn't think of this lol.